# Input Apache Spark MlLib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

What kind of input can I give my ML algorithms from Spark?
There are streaming algorithms like StreamingKMeans or StreamingLinearRegression.
These can have an input stream for training and testing.

In addition, there are many other algorithms, such as ALS or Decision Tree, which in the examples on the Spark website have only been trained and tested with static datasets.

My question is if I can take a streaming dataset for algorithms that are not designed for streaming.

For example:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html . This exmaple only reads from static files. Can I use a streaming input for this algorithm?

Comment: How do you receive your streaming data? Is it possible to get a DataFrame (with spark.readStream ... load()), and then do just like in your tutorial: "val Array(train, test) = dataset.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2)), val model = new ALS() ... fit(train)"? I have no spark at hand, but this may work

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot split a streaming Dataset in Spark like in the tutorial.